# Copy rotation constraint adjusting influence doesn't work

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

In the gif below, I applied a copy rotation constraint to the lower bone of the upper arm. It is copying the rotation of the larger bone directly on top of it. While the influence is set to 1.00, it works fine, but the moment I turn it down the entire bone flips to a completely different direction. I made sure it is copying the correct bone, and the rotation is set to local space.
[image]

[image]

This is the effect I'm trying to achieve
[image]

It may be just a problem with the armature itself. In a separate file, I recreated the shoulder area with the same constraints, and it worked perfectly. The mesh does not get messed up when I add the copy rotation constraint or adjust the influence. If it works here, then what is causing the constraint to fail in my original file?
[image]

Comment: Try pose to pose space.

Comment: Where do I find that; edit: never mind it doesn't work. It has the same effect

Comment: Please show both models.  Two images to show the problem would be good.  The gif is not clear IMHO.  Have owner of the constraint be in rest position ... clear all rotations.  Please show the simplest test case.

Comment: I updated my post with another gif. Hopefully this better explains my problem. You can now see the control bone I want it to be constrained to as well as seeing the process in which I applied the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try on edit mode, go to the arms and reset the roll value for both bones Alt+R